# flash geturl in new window with scrollbars=yes in Action Script

Tags: flash, geturl

Can some one help me to do this effects in flash?

I have this code for `getURL` but it's opening in newtab. What I need is it should be open in new window.

```
on(release){getURL("http://www.google.com", "_blank");}
```

I want something like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open5).

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

`getURL` offers no window control. You'll need to use [getURL/navigateToURL with JavaScript](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/create-pop-browser-windows-flash.html#main_main_geturljs) to achieve that:

```
var jscommand:String = "window.open('http://www.google.com','win','height=400,width=400,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes');";  

getURL("javascript:" + jscommand + " void(0);");
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. I have added the code in my file, But when i press ctrl+enter it's working i don't what like that. after we click on some images it need to work please.

Comment: If I correctly understood, you whant to open that window when clicking on some image ?

Comment: For that you could use something like this : `click_btn_name.onRelease = function(){ //put here the above code}`, where `click_btn_name` is your button.

Comment: My code is like this:


anotherSite_btn.onRelease = function(){
 var jscommand:String = "window.open('http://www.google.com','win','height=400,width=400,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes');";  

 getURL("javascript:" + jscommand + " void(0);");
}

and it is giving some error massage.

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 6', Frame 1, Line 1 1119: Access of possibly undefined property onRelease through a reference with static type flash.display:SimpleButton.

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 6', Frame 1, Line 4 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method getURL.

Comment: I guess you're using AS3 ! Try this instead : `anotherSite_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:MouseEvent):void {//your code here});`